# Loop through text file after filtering out comments in C

Tags: c, file, filter, io, comments

I am trying to filter out comments from a text file denoted by '#'.  I am having trouble looping through the entire file and printing the output to the terminal. The code removes the first line of text and the second lines comments as it should but does not continue past line 2 (prints 4, 2), any help would be appreciated. I'm definitely missing something as I have had to learn two semesters of C in a weekend and don't totally have a grasp on all of its usage.

The file being read

```
# this line is a full comment that might be pseudo-code or whatever
4, 2 # 4, 3  
1  
# 9  
7  
endNode  
endNet
```

The program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFF_SIZE 1024
#define COMMENT_MARKER '#'
int main()
{

FILE *fp;
char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];

if ((fp = fopen("F:\\PythonProjects\\C\\text.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
    perror("Error opening file");
    exit(1);
}

while (fgets(buffer, BUFF_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
{
    char *comment = strchr(buffer, COMMENT_MARKER);
    if (comment != NULL)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(comment);
        memset(comment, '\0', len);
        printf("%s", buffer);
        
    }
}
fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Your code only prints out a line if it originally contains a `#` character.

Comment: (You also don't need a `memset()`; just `if (comment) *comment = 0;` followed by printing `buffer` will do. Just remember to take into account that removing the comment will strip off the newline at the end of the line).

Comment: Take the `printf()` out of the `if` block.

Comment: Are lines that are only comments meant to be output as blank lines, or suppressed completely?

Comment: @Fe2O3 Suppressed completely is what I'm going for.  I have it working almost how I need it to but when I remove a comment that is on a line that is mid connection count it messes up the output and prints a junk value.  This is happening (I think) because I am looping connection count amount of times and the blank like is taking one of those counts.  I know I need to remove the blank but cant find anything in c that is akin to Java's remove method.

Comment: @nerb What is "connection count"? I've replied with a suggestion to suppress "empty" lines below my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code only prints out a line if a `#` is found in it. It skips printing lines without any comment. And because you set everything from the first `#` to the end of the string to nul bytes, it won't print a newline after each line, meaning the results all run together.

You can fix these issues by moving the output *after* the comment removal block, and always printing out a newline. This means that in lines without comments, you have to do something about the newline at the end (if any; it could be missing because of a long line or the input file lacking one after the last line) so you don't get two newlines after each non-comment line.

Luckily, there are ways in standard C to find the first occurrence of one of a set of character, not just a single character. You can look for either the comment character *or* newline in a single pass through the line, and replace it with a single nul byte - no need to `memset()` everything after it to 0's. Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // Needed for exit()

#define BUFF_SIZE 1024
#define COMMENT_MARKER '#'

int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];

  if ((fp = fopen("text.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
      perror("Error opening file");
      exit(1);
    }

  char tokens[3] = { COMMENT_MARKER, '\n', '\0' };
  
  while (fgets(buffer, BUFF_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
    {
      // Look for the first # or newline in the string
      char *comment_or_nl = strpbrk(buffer, tokens);
      if (comment_or_nl)
        {
          // and if found, replace it with a nul byte
          *comment_or_nl = '\0';
        }
      // Then print out the possibly-truncated string (puts() adds a newline)
      puts(buffer);
    }
  
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to be really robust, you have to account for a line longer than `BUFFER_LEN` chars that has a `#` in the first `BUFFER_LEN` section...

Comment: "Really robust" would not use `puts()` that will insert its own '\n' breaking up really long lines into multiple lines... Just to say... `:-)`...

Comment: This solved my problem and showed me the answer to problems I didn't know I had yet. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, minimally adapted to achieve the objective.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFF_SIZE 1024
#define COMMENT_MARKER '#'

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("F:\\PythonProjects\\C\\text.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE]; // declare variables proximate to use
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFF_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
    {
        char *comment = strchr(buffer, COMMENT_MARKER);
        if (comment != NULL)
        {
            strcpy( comment, "\n" ); // Just clobber the comment section
        }
        printf("%s", buffer); // Always print something
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up going with. Thanks a ton

Comment: @nerb If you want to suppress lines that _had been_ only a comment, simply put `if( buf[0] != '\n' )` ahead of the printf... Only non-empty lines will be output... :-) Thanks for the positive feedback `:-)`